# Create composite index from a Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models

class PopulationData(models.Model):
    slot = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    sample = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('slot', 'sample'),)
```

And I would like to create also a compound index on the column pair that have the `UNIQUE` constraint, like so:

```sql
CREATE INDEX my_compound_index ON myapp_populationdata (slot, sample);
```

Right now I have a separate code connected to the `post_syncdb` signal that issues the previous SQL statement.  Is there any way to indicate it from the model specification?  (Note: I'm using the 1.3 branch).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Starting from django-1.5 you can make compound index using `index_together` meta option:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#index-together

**Note (2023/01/30)** `index_together` is deprecated since django-4.2. Instead, use much more powerful `indexes` meta option. With it you can create not only compound indexes, but also other types of indexes, e.g. function-based indexes, partial (conditional) indexes, covering indexes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.indexes

So, in your example index declaration would like this

```
from django.db import models

class PopulationData(models.Model):
    slot = models.IntegerField()
    sample = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index("slot", "sample", name="population_slot_sample_idx")
        ]
```

Comment: new link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#index-together

Comment: latest link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#index-together

Answer (score 8):

Starting from Django-1.11 use Meta.indexes option https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/indexes/:

```
from django.db import models

class PopulationData(models.Model):
    slot = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    sample = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('slot', 'sample'),)
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['slot', 'sample']),
        ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Since a *unique constraint* also creates an index, it would be **counterproductive** to create both.

for example, from the **[`postgres docs`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-unique.html)**:

> There's no need to manually create indexes on unique columns; doing so would just duplicate the automatically-created index.

Credit to [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531703/10746224) for the doc link

If for some reason you still want to create a multi-column index, you can do so via `index_together`:

```
class PopulationData(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        index_together = [['slot', 'sample']]
```

Comment: It can't be the same index when one is compound though. They have completely different purposes. I don't see how it could result in creating the same index

Answer (score 2):

I think that's not currently implemented in the django ORM.

If you use a migration tool (like south) that might be a good place to add that sql statement or if you preffer to avoid raw sql you could use sqlalchemy (core) but this case sounds simple enough to just go with sql.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** *index_together* may be deprecated in the future:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#index-together

Use indexes in the Meta class instead:

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name']),
            models.Index(fields=['first_name'], name='first_name_idx'),
        ]
```